# How do I insert an array into single field of my SQL table using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have checkbox entries that I am appending to a list by their html name, like so:

```
    Choose no more than three categories:<br>
    <input id='category1' type="checkbox" name="boxsize[]" 
    onclick="CountChecks('listone',3,this)" value="asian">Asian
    <input id='category2' type="checkbox" name="boxsize[]" 
    onclick="CountChecks('listone',3,this)" value="asianFusion">Asian Fusion
```

I have many other checkboxes as well. I then implode this list by doing:

```
    $sanentry=implode(',',$_REQUEST["boxsize"]);
```

When I echo $sanentry I get a list of the selected values in the following format: asian, asian fusion. However when I try to send these values to my ethnicity table in mysql the ethnicity column is empty. Here is the post method and query I am using to send these values to my table.

```
    $sanethnicity=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['$sanentry']);
    $sql3="INSERT INTO 
    ethnicity(restaurant_id,ethnicity)VALUES('$sanrestid','$sanethnicity')";
    if ($con->query($sql3) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record in ethnicity table created \n";
    } else {
    die("Error: " . $sql3 . "<br>" . $con->error);
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

There is no problem with my restaurant_id column as that is being updated fine but for every new row inserted the ethnicity column always comes up blank. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GYfJ.png)

Comment: Typo? Change `$_POST['$sanentry']` to `$_POST['sanentry']`

Comment: you are just trying to insert a string technically. maybe the string is to long for the column or something. you are not getting any sql errors? what does the sql profiler say?

Comment: I'm not getting an SQL errors

Comment: The ethnicity column just shows up blank each time

Comment: Also I made the constraints for the ethnicity column varchar(255) so it should be too long for the column

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== true`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing the variable name is wrong.   should be `$sanethnicity` you've got `$ethnicitydb` in your query.

```
$sql3="INSERT INTO ethnicity(restaurant_id,ethnicity) VALUES('$sanrestid','$sanethnicity')";
```

Also, is this the field that has raw ethicity array? `$_POST['$sanentry']` or has that been imploded.  You probably want this:

```
$sanethnicity=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $sanethnicity);
```

Since the `$sanethnicity` was prior imploded from seomthing like:

```
$sanethnicity = implode(',',$_REQUEST["boxsize"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line your trying to use $sanentry as an entry in $_POST...

```
$sanethnicity=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['$sanentry']);
```

Should be

```
$sanethnicity=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $sanentry);
```

Although - you should be looking into using prepared statements and bind variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store it without losing the array structure then you should use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)